# F4 (Describe) doesn't work on Toad version 9.6 for viewing tables

Tags: toad

Problem: Unable to view 'Table' on pressing F4 (describe) on Toad (Version 9.6.1.1). Although I am able to view functions/ packages / procedures.

Tried : 1. Re-opening TOAD.
        2. Checking for the settings.
        3. Modified TOAD.INI (before I checked that I was able to view functions and packages); deleted 'ColCommentsHeight'.

Possible Explanation : 1. Access issue / 2. Settings issue

Is there anything else I can do to view 'Tables'? Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Are all tables inaccessible or only those in a particular schema?

Comment: All tables are inaccessible.

Comment: Toad 9.6 is old and I no longer have it installed, but somewhere there's an option to spool SQL to screen or you can launch SQL Monitor (or SQL Tracker) which should be installed in the same folder as Toad. Start monitoring Toad or enable SQL spooling to screen within Toad and press F4 on your table name. Look at the queries that Toad is executing to resolve the reference. You should see one in there for accessing user_tables, all_tables, dba_tables, dba_all_tables, etc. Also look in the spooled SQL for ORA errors. You should see one for any selects on objects you can't access.

Comment: I was able to view the statements that are being triggered. Sys Tables are being referrenced, so this isn't access issue. Thanks Michael...This might have to do something related to settings?

Comment: I can't think of any setting that would cause this, but if you close Toad and rename Toad.ini and restart you'll start with fresh options. If you don't see tables then there is something else going on. You could always try downloading the latest Toad freeware and see if it works. Your version is very outdated. There could have been a bug fixed, etc.